# TensorFlow Object Detection API (Different interest)

Tags: tensorflow

I have one question.
I trained 2 times one and the same model. For training I used a ready-made model with 90 classes. And I get different percentages of recognition. Why? As far as I understand, if you train your model on an already finished one, then the initial weights will always be the same and therefore the results should always be the same.

Comment: Is it possible to substantiate your last statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you took some pre-trained model, and fine-tuned it two different times, but with the same configuration.
If so, not only the two resulting models do no have to be the same, moreover - they most probably won't be.

The reason for that is that the training procedure has some random options in it, e.g. data shuffling, augmentation, dropout, etc.
For example, a common augmentation option is to randomly flip an image horizontally. This means that in one training session an image can be taken as is, while in the other - its mirror image.

While this is only one example, quite a few random options are made with different probabilities, and therefore you can't achieve the **exact same** model unless you document each and every choice your training session makes.

Comment: How do I document every choice my training makes?